# Remove all users from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

we have recently migrated our TFS 2010 to TFS 2013, We have converted our old projects from tfs2010 to tfs2013 for the new server. since this is a new machine and we need to remove all the previous users form our project and start with new users?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. The powershell in below URL will give you all users and I think you can add a step to remove the user. I haven't tried it but I think it should work.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2013/03/07/using-powershell-and-tfs-api-to-list-users-in-tfs-2010.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In Team Explorer, connect to the team project collection from which you are removing a user.
For more information, see [Connect to and Access Team Projects in Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Right-click the collection, point to **Team Project Collection Settings**, and then click **Security**.

The **Global Security** dialog box opens.

In the **Users and groups** list, click the user whom you want to remove, and **click Remove**.

When you are prompted to confirm the removal, click **Yes**.

In the **Global Security dialog** box, click **Close**.

**[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253182%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**